# What could I improve on on my monkey model?

Tags: modeling

So I made this monkey model and I am no expert on modeling so I was wondering if you guys could take a look and give me feedback! If you want to look at the file download it at:https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByrMQl4A3FTwcUVSalF2WXZ5Slk/view?usp=sharing  Thanks![image: ![Here it is]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xETGz.png)

Comment: Recalculate normals in Edit mode for body part of mesh. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/why-are-some-faces-in-my-mesh-darker. Aside from that I think this is not really a question about using Blender which is out of scope of Blender.SE.

Comment: Blender Artists is a more appropriate place for this subjective question stated without criteria.  Where did you come up with that interesting monkey face?  Perhaps you can ask a question such as .... How can I get a rounder back for the monkey?  Then that would not be so subjective.

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger - isn't that just the monkey face that ships with blender?  http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?274119-The-Blender-Monkey

Comment: @Baronz Is it?  I though it was more Lancelot Link Secret Chimp featuring Mata Hari.

Comment: oooh.. i love it. but sadly this isn't in the scope of our site! come to this chat room and i'd be happy to help you: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8888/the-renderfarm%5C

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger Thank you yes it is the monkey that comes with blender but I made the rest!

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger LOL :D

Answer (score 1):

JUST SOME TIPS: The body part topology of your model is decent, though hands and legs' topology is too dense. Try to keep it as simple as it can be (start to model fingers using a circle with only 8 vertices).
[image]

Do the same for the toes (see my topology suggestion below).
[image]
[image]

Always start with a simpliest shapes and then slowly add more geometry.
Your question reminds me this one: [How to retopologize my model?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39791/how-to-retopologize-my-model) Wish I have more time right now to retopologize this model for you and show you some simple solutions, but I'm quite busy right now :(.

Remember, that simple and smart topology is a key to make the model bend well while animating (simple finger model topology bend example here: [How do rigs relate to weights?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46315/how-do-rigs-relate-to-weights))

Comment: Monkeys do not have feet like that.  How would they hold a banana?  They have beautiful hairy feet.

Comment: Male monkeys doesn't have feet like that, I agree. Please notice, that I've presented a FEMALE monkey feet. Modern female monkeys shaves feet regulary nowadays.

Comment: Oh its a Show Monkey, very High Gloss.