# Rig deforming shape when rotating

Tags: rigging

I'm trying to learn rigging, so I started with very very simple character model. But when I weighted head vertexes and tried to rotate bone, the head became deformed as top of the head had lower weight then the bottom part of head.

Weights:
[image: Weights]

Head bone rotated to front site:
[image: Deformed head]

Any idea what did I do wrong? I tried to follow video tutorial on youtube, where it worked correctly right away, but with a bit complicated character model.

Thanks a lot for all help!

Comment: see this exact copy of your question: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46315/how-do-rigs-relate-to-weights/46322#46322

Comment: Could you please upload your .blend file to be able to help you?

Comment: @joshsanfelici thanks, you're right. It wasn't obvious because the weights were assign to some totally unrelated bone by some accident. I looked at every single bone and found the issue.

Comment: exactly! Position of vertices is a weighted sum of all influences of all defoming bones to whom the vertex is weighted, but if a vertex is weighted to one bone only, also a weight of 0.00001 will result in 100 percent movement, because 0.00001 is infinitely higher than 0.0