# Why are my bones bendy? Rigging

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

**I also figured out the reason it didn't work in the first place, I didn't name the bones and vertexes the same name.**

I had an issue when my mesh was not moving with my bones, I've managed to fix it but now I have another problem.

Now when my bones bend it kinda looks like that scene from harry potter where the teacher tries to fix harrys broken arm. Actually it's kinda funny because in this situation I'm that teacher.

Is there a solution to this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think doing what's described here [How do rigs relate to weights?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46315/how-do-rigs-relate-to-weights/46322#46322) will help.

If you parent the mesh to the bones 'with automatic weights', it *should* try to correctly weight paint the mesh to the bones fairly well. And if still looks 'weird' on some parts such as 'too sharp' bending, or 'too soft' (like what you're experiencing), then you need to adjust the weight painting a bit.

hope it helps!